# wrong output on printing subsets of array

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to print all the subsets of an array. But not getting the correct output.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5};
int n=5;

void print(int a[],int cnt, int idx)
{
    if(idx==n)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<cnt;i++)
        {
            cout<<a[i]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
        return;
    }
    a[cnt]=arr[idx];
    print(a,cnt,idx+1);
    print(a,cnt+1,idx+1);
}
int main()
{
    int a[5]={0};
    print(a,0,0);
}
```

the above code only prints "5"
Please help me to rectify the same.

Comment: A `print` function typically does not modify the thing it is printing.  What is the purpose of modifying `a` in your print function?

Comment: a will store the values of array arr.

Comment: You might be interested by [Powerset section of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25556248/2684539).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the array with a vector. As the array in `C++` is passed by reference, the print function is accessing the same array, which causes the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5};
int n=5;

void print(vector<int>a,int cnt, int idx)
{
    if(idx==n)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<cnt;i++)
        {
            cout<<a[i]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
        return;
    }
    a[cnt]=arr[idx];
    print(a,cnt,idx+1);
    print(a,cnt+1,idx+1);
}
int main()
{
    vector<int >a(5,0);
    print(a,0,0);
}
```